# Angular 5 in EJS file while rendering that Template from Node JS

Tags: node.js, angular, ejs

I was making HTML Render from Node js so that i can show things on angular side,

But their are some Directives of angular which I want to set in EJS Rendering, so that the directive magic should happens on UI when it is render.

The problem here is coming that EJS is not allowing to put angular Directives in its format. Is their any possible way for this.

Angular 5 in EJS file while rendering that Template from Node JS.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer : **don't do that**.

Using angular isn't using a library : using Angular means your are using **a whole platform**.

You write your code in Typescript, which is then compiled to vanilla Javascript. This means, once your code is compiled, the syntax you're using to make Angular component changes too.

In your case, you use NodeJS to serve static pages : **The very principle of Angular is to create SPA (Single Page Applications)**. If you create static files that you serve with a server, then what is the point of creating a SPA ?

So the answer is : don't use EJS to create templates that will contain Angular components. I don't even know if it is possible, but in any case, this is a very bad practice.

Comment: So, what is practice should i prefer to render HTML pages ? which also helps me to navigate on links from that HTML and route appends to the current url ( which would be specify in href in HTML ) ?

Comment: Well you can use Angular or EJS, but not both. Angular has a routing strategy since it create SPA, but if you don't know that, then maybe you should not use Angular ...